# How to Automate the Save As command for multiple open files in Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, templates, preview, save-as

I use Mac OS to run a daily business utility that will create eleven (11) reports printed to PDF and the files open in Mac Preview.  The files are created with generic filenames such as "Constant.pdf" or "Estimate.pdf".  I have a folder with blank PDF files that I use as a "template" for saving these files with the appropriate filenames.  Each blank PDF file has the filename I want to use for each of the open PDF reports.  I do this manually by taking the first open PDF,
pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (to access the Save As command), highlight the file I want to "Save To" in the Finder window, click "Save", click "Replace", then I close the PDF file.  I repeat this step with of the remaining 10 files.

I would hope there is a way to automate these steps.  Fortunately the PDF files are printed/created in a specific sequence and Preview opens the files in that sequence and they appear in the same sequence as I manually Save As and close the files.  So the automator would need to know which filenames to assign to each PDF in order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yup, easy.  What happens to the PDF files after they're saved ?  Do they stay there, or get moved ?  Because I'm wondering, then, what happens the next day, and how the next 11 get named—presumably differently to the 11 from the previous day ?  Also, do all 11 PDF files open quite quickly in sequence, or is it more like one PDF file per hour ?

Comment: The 11 PDF's are created and opened in approx a minute maybe two.  Too quick to manually save each filae as they are opened.

Comment: Sorry hit return.. The files are saved in unique folders with unique path names. I have a "template" folder that I duplicate and rename each time I need to produce these reports.

Comment: Good - actually, for a script, the faster, the better. And a script is how you would solve your problem, i.e. AppleScript.  Also, would you be willing to name your template PDFs with a leading index number that tells a script the order in which to name files?  For example, your third PDF template currently named `"some_file_name.pdf"` would become `"3-some_file_name.pdf"`, which would then result in the third PDF to be processed being saved as `"some_file_name.pdf"` (without the `"3-"`).

Comment: Yes I can add that to each template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder where your 11 PDF templates can reside permanently.  Prefix their filenames with `01-`, `02-`, ..., `10-`, `11-` to indicate the order in which processed PDFs will be saved (it is important that templates 1-9 have a leading `0` in front).

In the script below, change the value of the property `templatesFolder` (line 1) to reflect the path to the folder where the PDF templates can be found.

To use the script, allow all 11 PDFs to be processed to open in *Preview*, then run the script.  You can incorporate the script into an *Automator* **service**, and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.  Instructions on [how to make a systemwide service with *Automator*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/MakeaSystem-WideService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH46-SW1) can be found at that link.

When run, the script will open a file system dialog that will allow you to select a folder where you would like the processed PDFs to be saved.  **`Cancel`** will abort the script.  Once you click **`Choose`**, the PDF files will be saved in the order they were opened, using the filenames of the template PDFs (but without the prefix).  Each PDF is then closed, *Preview* is closed, and the saved PDFs are revealed in *Finder*.

#### The Script:

```
property templatesFolder : "~/Documents/PDFs/Templates"

set saveFolder to POSIX path of ¬
    (choose folder with prompt ("Select a folder to save PDFs") ¬
        default location path to documents folder)

tell application "System Events" to set pdfTemplates to the ¬
    name of the files in folder templatesFolder ¬
    whose name extension is "pdf"

set filenames to sort(the result)

repeat with D in my getPreviewDocumentsInOrder()
    set filename to text 4 thru -1 of item 1 of filenames
    set fp to POSIX file ([saveFolder, filename] as text)
    tell application "Preview"
        save D in fp
        close D
    end tell
    set filenames to rest of filenames
    if filenames = {} then exit repeat
end repeat

quit application "Preview"

tell application "Finder"
    open POSIX file saveFolder
    activate
end tell
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
###HANDLERS
#
#
to getPreviewDocumentsInOrder()
    script
        use P : application "Preview"
        property idx : sort(id of P's windows)

        on docList(IDs)
            local IDs

            if IDs = {} then return {}
            script
                property L : IDs
            end script

            tell the result to set [d0, dN] to [first item, rest] of its L
            tell P to return {document of window id (d0)} & my docList(dN)
        end docList
    end script

    tell the result to return the docList(its idx)
end getPreviewDocumentsInOrder

to sort(L as list)
    local L

    if L = {} then return {}
    if L's length = 1 then return L

    script
        property Array : L

        on minimum(L as list)
            local L

            if L is {} then return {}
            if L's length = 1 then return L's first item

            script
                property Array : L
            end script

            set [x0, xN] to [first item, rest] of the result's Array
            set min to minimum(xN)
            if x0 < min then return x0
            return min
        end minimum

        on lastIndexOf(x, L as list)
            local x, L

            if x is not in L then return {}
            if L = {} then return

            script
                property Array : L
            end script

            tell the result
                set [x0, xN] to [last item, reverse of rest of reverse] of its Array
                if x0 = x then return (xN's length) + 1
                return lastIndexOf(x, xN)
            end tell
        end lastIndexOf

        to swap(L as list, i as integer, j as integer)
            local i, j, L

            set x to item i of L
            set item i of L to item j of L
            set item j of L to x
        end swap
    end script

    tell the result
        set i to lastIndexOf(minimum(its Array), its Array)
        if i ≠ 1 then swap(its Array, 1, i)
        set [x0, xN] to [first item, rest] of its Array
        return [x0] & sort(xN)
    end tell
end sort
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  Is there a way I can make the default "choose" path to be something like the following... DaveC:Users:Dave:Documents:Company:Audits:Reports:Projects.    Would save having to drill down to choose the save path.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes - if you look on the fifth line, part of the `choose folder` command is a property called `default location`, which you can set to whatever folder you like as the default "choose" path.  You can either set it like this, with a posix path: `default location POSIX file "/Users/CK/Documents"`; or using an HFS path: `default location alias "Macintosh HD:Users:CK:Documents:"`.

Comment: When I add this code I get the following message "Can’t make "Dave Clark:Users:dclark:Documents:Company Stuff:Project Audits:New Financial Reporting:Reports" into type constant."  Is the path too long?

Also the script works perfect in my test folder, but when I put into the production with the actual files it skips the first file.  Any ideas???

Comment: You haven’t written the `default location` property out the way I described.  You left in `path to`.  As for why it appears to work in one place and not another, I can’t see a reason why that would be.  I need more information about what makes your test folder and your production folder or their files different.

Comment: I apologize.  I'm not a student of Applescript and I took your instructions literally.  Please forgive me.  You've been so helpful.  Is there a way I can send you screen shots of the folder structure?

Comment: The difference was in my test folder I had created unique dummy files with sequential numbering so it was easy to follow the script.  In the production version the PDF files all have the same name (see screen shot I sent to your dropbox).  Once I figured out which file was 01, which was 02, and so forth, I was able to add a "dummy" file in the templates folder with the missing number and it now it works fine.  I think it had to do with the way Preview was sorting the files in the Window menu, because the top one in the list was the one that was being skipped.  It works now. Thanks!

Comment: This Workflow has worked very well until recently.  Our 3rd party platform changed the way it handles creating the PDF files and even though they are created in the same order, the Workflow doesn't save them in the correct order.  I tried renumbering the template files, but still can't get it work 100% of the time.  So I was able to get the PDF files created with unique filenames.